# Letter shortcuts switched to number shortcuts

Tags: interface, shortcut

As the title says suddenly most of my shortcuts have been reset to numbers instead of letters.
I remember clearly that the "sample" shortcut from texture paint was "s" and now is "1"

[image: img1]